# Why am I getting an NA when calculating the mean?

Tags: r

Every time I try to calculate this line "DHS <- mean(ahebachelors2008) - mean(ahebachelors1992)" I receive an NA answer. Calculating mean(ahe2008) works but calculating mean(ahebachelors2008) does not work.

```
setwd("~/Google Drive/R Data")
data <- read.csv('cps92_08.csv')
year <- data$year
year1992 <- subset(data,year<2000)
year2008 <- subset(data,year>2000)
ahe1992 <- (year1992$ahe)
ahe2008 <- (year2008$ahe)
max(ahe1992)
min(ahe1992)
mean(ahe1992)
median(ahe1992)
sd(ahe1992)
max(ahe2008)
min(ahe2008)
mean(ahe2008)
median(ahe2008)
sd(ahe2008)

adjahe <- ahe1992*(215.2/140.3)
max(adjahe)
min(adjahe)
mean(adjahe)
median(adjahe)
sd(adjahe)

D <- mean(ahe2008) - mean(adjahe)

education <- data$bachelor
ahebachelors1992 <- subset(adjahe, education>0)
ahehighschool1992 <- subset(adjahe,education<1)
ahebachelors2008 <- subset(ahe2008,education>0)
ahehighschool2008 <- subset(ahe2008,education<1)

DHS <- mean(ahebachelors2008) - mean(ahebachelors1992)
```

Comment: What's in `ahebachelors2008`? Is there any NA in there? run `which(is.na(ahebachelors2008))`? Or maybe there's just nothing in it at all?

Comment: You probably have NA in your dataframe, you should use the argument `na.rm = TRUE` in your calculation of  `mean`. Check the documentation `?mean()`

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`) and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: in ahebachelors2008 is the data for which average hourly earnings for people with a bachelors degree was calculated in 2008. i am so sorry if i am not answering your questions properly, i just started R two weeks ago so this is so so new for me! is there any information that i could share with you that will help you help me better?

i ran the function which(is.na(ahebachelors2008)) there are 6594 data points in there.

Comment: okay so i just checked the whole ahebachelors 2008 and noticed that out of 6594 datapoints, there are 2953 with figures --- the rest all contain NA. how would i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`education` is the same length as `data`, whereas `ahe2008` is a subset of `data`. So when you pass `education` as the condition on `ahe2008`, it creates NAs (because that's the corresponding value in ahe2008 for those elements.

Here's a simpler example:

```
d1<-c(1:5)
d2<-c(1:5,1:5)
subset(d1,d2==1)
[1]  1 NA
```

Possible solutions would be to create separate `bachelor` vectors for each year, or to not continuously subset but just use multiple conditions where you need them.

If you're trying to avoid typing the full `data$something` every time, consider using `with()`, or even better - the `dplyr` package.

For example, all the code leading up to the last line could be replaced with this (assuming I didn't miss anything):

```
DHS <- mean(with(data,ahe[year>2000 & education>0])) - 
       mean(with(data,ahe[year<2000 & education>0]*(215.2/140.3))
```

(If you're new to R, note that the `[]` structure is a simpler way to call on subset).

You might also want to consider using `summary` which will give you min, median, mean, and max, leaving you with just `sd` to add manually.:

```
summary(with(data,ahe[year>2000]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!

Can you help me with an example that uses multiple conditions, how would I formulate that on R?

Comment: @sakina see my expanded answer above.

Comment: oh my god! thank you so so so much. this was my first post on stackoverflow and i was not too sure if i would be able to get help! thank you so much! i will be sure to look around for an 'iod' commenting on my future posts.

Answer (score -1):

If the values you are trying to calculate `mean` on contain NA then the output will be NA. You can overcome it by adding `na.rm = TRUE` to your mean:

```
DHS <- mean(ahebachelors2008, na.rm=TRUE) - mean(ahebachelors1992, na.rm=TRUE)
```